# expected ndim = 4 found ndim = 5 and other errors - Keras - GTSRB dataset

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, training-data

I'm trying to make a CNN model based on the GTSRB dataset (link given below), but I'm faced with the following error:

When I set the input_shape = input_shape=(3, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE), I get this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_34_input to
>   have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (9030, 1)

When I researched the problem, I found that one solution may be passing the batch_size as a parameter, when I try that, I get this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_40: expected
>   ndim=4, found ndim=5

When I try to reshape the training_images, I get this error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9030 into shape (48,48,3)

Snippets of the code:
Loading the training dataset:

```
import csv

# Training dataset
def readTrafficSignsTrain(rootpath):
    '''Reads traffic sign data for German Traffic Sign Recognition Benchmark.

    Arguments: path to the traffic sign data, for example './GTSRB/Training'
    Returns:   list of images, list of corresponding labels'''
    images = [] # images
    labels = [] # corresponding labels

    # loop over all 42 classes
    for c in range(0,43):
#         prefix = rootpath + '/' + format(c, '05d') + '/' # subdirectory for class
#         annFile = open(prefix + 'GT-'+ format(c, '05d') + '.csv') # annotations file
        prefix = rootpath + '/00000' + '/'
        annFile = open(prefix + 'GT-00000' + '.csv')
        annReader = csv.reader(annFile, delimiter=';') # csv parser for annotations file
        next(annReader, None) # skip header

        # loop over all images in current annotations file
        for row in annReader:
            images.append(plt.imread(prefix + row[0])) # the 1st column is the filename
            labels.append(row[7]) # the 8th column is the label

        annFile.close()
    return images, labels

training_images, training_labels = readTrafficSignsTrain('./GTSRB/Training')
```

Here's a problem, the images shapes are not the same, for example

```
print(len(training_images))
print(len(training_labels))
print()
print(training_images[0].shape)
print(training_images[20].shape)
print(training_images[200].shape)
print(training_images[2000].shape)
```

Outputs

> 9030 9030
>
> (30, 29, 3) (54, 57, 3) (69, 63, 3) (52, 51, 3)

Layer setup (copied and pasted from a Keras documentation linked below):

```
IMG_SIZE = 48
NUM_CLASSES = 43
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')

batch_size = 32

def cnn_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     input_shape=(3, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
                     activation='relu',
                     data_format="channels_first"))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
    return model

model = cnn_model()
```

Training the model (just model.fit for the time being

```
import numpy

trim = numpy.array(training_images)
trlb = numpy.array(training_labels)

print(training_images[0].shape)
print(trim.shape)

trim - trim.reshape(48, 48, 3)

model.fit(trim, trlb, epochs = 30, batch_size = 32)
```

Output

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9030 into shape (48,48,3)

When I remove the reshape

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_41_input to
>   have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (9030, 1)

When I use this instead

```
model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs = 30, batch_size = 32)
```

Output

```
> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
> that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
> Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 9030
> arrays: [array([[[ 75,  78,  80],
>             [ 74,  76,  78],
>             [ 86,  87,  84],
>             ...,
>             [ 68,  75,  75],
>             [ 65,  69,  68],
>             [ 66,  67,  66]],
>     
>            [[ 83,  84,  86],
>             [...
```

So, if I do that (not really sure why)

```
for i in range(len(training_images)):
    model.fit(training_images[i], training_labels[i], epochs = 30, batch_size = 32)
```

I get

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_41_input to
>   have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 29, 3)

That is with

```
input_shape=(3, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)
```

If I make

```
input_shape=(batch_size, 3, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)
```

I get

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_47: expected
>   ndim=4, found ndim=5

Output of model.summary()

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_34 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 48, 48)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_35 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 46, 46)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_14 (MaxPooling (None, 32, 23, 23)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_14 (Dropout)         (None, 32, 23, 23)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_36 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 23, 23)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_37 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 21, 21)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPooling (None, 64, 10, 10)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 64, 10, 10)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_38 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 10, 10)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_39 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 8, 8)         147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_16 (MaxPooling (None, 128, 4, 4)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_16 (Dropout)         (None, 128, 4, 4)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)          (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 512)               1049088   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_17 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 43)                22059     
=================================================================
Total params: 1,358,155
Trainable params: 1,358,155
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

If anyone can help, that would be mostly appreciated.

Links
GTSRB: http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=news
Keras documentation I got the model from: https://chsasank.github.io/keras-tutorial.html

Link for the full project on github: https://github.com/PavlySz/TSR-Project

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reshape an np.array to something the dimesions do not allow. Here is what you can do

```
import numpy as np 
img_arr = np.array([np.ones((30, 29, 3)), 
                    np.ones((54, 57, 3)), 
                    np.ones((69, 63, 3)), 
                    np.ones((52, 51, 3))])

print(img_arr.shape)

import cv2
img_arr_conv = np.array([cv2.resize(img, dsize=(48, 48)) for img in img_arr])
print(img_arr_conv.shape)

>>>(4,)
>>>(4, 48, 48, 3)
```

You were getting the `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9030 into shape (48,48,3)` because numpy cannot infer the dimensions of an array if the elements are all different sizes and it cannot reshape an array that the dimensions do not allow. This is also the case for `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_41_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (9030, 1)`. Numpy only knows there are 9030 elements in the array. It cannot do anything more than that because all the dimensions of the elements are different.
Example

```
img_arr_bad = np.array([np.ones((30, 29, 3)), 
                        np.ones((54, 57, 3)), 
                        np.ones((69, 63, 3)), 
                        np.ones((52, 51, 3))])

img_arr_good = np.array([np.ones((48, 48, 3)), 
                         np.ones((48, 48, 3)), 
                         np.ones((48, 48, 3)), 
                         np.ones((48, 48, 3))])

print(img_arr_bad.shape)
print(img_arr_good.shape)

>>>(4,)
>>>(4, 48, 48, 3)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So, a possible fix would be passing say img_width and img_height to input_shape? As such input_shape(3, img_width, img_height)

Comment: No, I am saying resize your images to be the same ```img_arr_conv = np.array([cv2.resize(img, dsize=(48, 48)) for img in training_images])```

Comment: Will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, good sir. You have no idea how much time I have wasted on this error. Guess I was just being dumb. Again, thank you!